# How to properly handle changes in a JSON file?

Tags: c#

I wrote a code that read all the items from a json that contains all the configuration of my application. In this code I've a property called `obj`:

```
public static SuperModel obj
{
    get
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(SettingsConfig.ConfigFilePath);
        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SuperModel>(json);
        return jsonObj;
    }
}
```

`SuperModel` is the class model that contains instance of other classes.
What I'm trying to achieve is update the json value and then call another method that should overwrite the file with the new json, like this:

```
Settings.obj.GeneralSettings.Language = "english";
Settings.Save();
```

But I've a problem, how can I monitor the change on `obj`, for example in this case I've updated the `Language` property of `GeneralSettings` -> `SuperModel` class, is possible store the updated object with `Save()` method that overwrite the file? 
I never encountered a similar situation.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You don't need to detect changes if you're going to serialize the object to file again: if it's the same, nothing changes (except for the last modified date of the file), and if it's different, the file gets updated. What _exactly_ do you need this functionality for, and what did your research show? See for example [What is the best practice to check if an object is changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071482/what-is-the-best-practice-to-check-if-an-object-is-changed).

Comment: @CodeCaster I need to pass the updated object to the file for update the json file, that's why I need to detect change

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246777/raise-an-event-whenever-a-propertys-value-changed

Comment: @CodeCaster what is not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. You don't want to "detect object updates", you want to keep a reference to a local variable that goes out of scope at your current `return` statement.

In order to do this, load the settings file only once, for example in a static constructor:

```
private static SuperModel _settingsObject;

static Settings
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(SettingsConfig.ConfigFilePath);
    var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SuperModel>(json);
    _settingsObject = jsonObj;
}
```

Then when a caller obtains the settings object, simply return the loaded object:

```
public static SuperModel obj
{
    get
    {
        return _settingsObject;
    }
}
```

Now any caller who alters the `SuperModel` instance returned by `Settings.obj`, directly modifies the instance known by the Settings class. So the Save() method saves the modified instance:

```
public static void Save()
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_settingsObject);
    File.WriteAllText(SettingsConfig.ConfigFilePath, json);
}
```

Also, look into naming guidelines for .NET. "obj" isn't really a useful identifier.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are trying to solve primarily *is not* about how to detect changes (which is well described in the [answer linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071482/what-is-the-best-practice-to-check-if-an-object-is-changed) by CodeCaster). The issue here is that your design is substantially flawed.

You are actually abusing a *property* to do what a *method* should do. Your property behaves as a *generator* of data, returning a new instance each time it is called (despite they would be the same from a value perspective). You never store the deserialized settings anywhere permanently, so it's not surprising there's no straightforward way to implement the `Save()` method.

Decouple your code and achieve a usage pattern like this:

```
Settings.LoadFromConfig();

… do whateever changes you need here …
Settings.MyConfig.GeneralSettings.Language = "english";

Settings.SaveToConfig();
```

The `LoadFromConfig` and `SaveFromConfig` methods should work with a `SuperModel` property, which can be simply declared like this:

```
public SuperModel MyConfig { get; private set; }
```

(The private setter ensures noone except the `Settings` class can create a new config instance.)

The actual implementation of `LoadFromConfig` and `SaveFromConfig` should be easy for you already.

Side note: It seems your `Settings` class is static. While it might make sense, it would generally be better to work rather work with an *instance*, although being a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: @Unchained My code? It's your code ;) Go ahead and implement the `SaveToConfig` method. It's trivial, the opposit of a load which you've already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the object, assuming you have multiple nested chains, you can make a hash of the object properties and store it somewhere (e.g. an **InitialHash** property).

Whenever you want to check for changes, you can rehash the object properties and compare it against the **InitialHash**. This will only give you info that the object properties was changed, but not what exactly was changed.